# URL string escape representation in objective-c? ("percent encoding")

Tags: objective-c, url, ios5, escaping

I want to make a very simple task in objective-c under **IOS5**: convert URL string to its escaped representation.

I tried a lot of ways to do it but neither seemed to work.

I can not make stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding work. It converts letters like áíűőüöúóé but does not convert others like =.

I'd like to have a function like Uri.EscapeDataString ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx ) in .net.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a category to `NSString` that does something like

```
- (NSString *)ps_stringByAddingPercentEscapes;
{
    return [(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                               (CFStringRef)self, 
                                                               NULL, 
                                                               (CFStringRef)@":/?#[]@!$&’()*+,;=", 
                                                               kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];
}
```

Replace `@":/?#[]@!$&’()*+,;="` for the chars that you care about.

Comment: Really surprising me...I thought it was a very simple and base feature that should be contained by the framework :O

Comment: It is! CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes is part of the OS frameworks.

Comment: @StilesCrisis I think he meant he assumed it would be a part of `Foundation`. It does seem odd having to drop down to `CoreFoundation`. The docs say `See CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapes for more complex transformations.` but I am also unsure why `NSASCIIStringEncoding` does not cover it already

Comment: SO, then which should be used? Which is the good one? There are several samples over the net and also yours here, and everywhere are pros and contras and 'but-s'. As a beginner in objective-c it is really shocking me. It is just some encoding :o

Comment: Whichever one best fits your needs is the best one.

Comment: The best fits? That is working for all possible problematic characters, like Uri.EscapeDataString in .net.

Comment: I don't know what characters that method works on so you'll need to do the deciding/research yourself. At least you have a good enough starting point now.

Comment: It can be any in UTF8 :)) But thanks anyway for your efforts, very kind from you!